# Cannot read property of undefined after Promise.promisify

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

```
let nasPath = "";
return getFamInfo(args.familyID)
    .then(function (famInfo) {
        nasPath = //some code involving famInfo here
        return getSFTPConnection(config.nasSettings);
    }).then(function (sftp) {
      const fastPutProm = Promise.promisify(sftp.fastPut);
      return fastPutProm(config.jpgDirectory, nasPath, {});
    });
```

If I put a breakpoint after `const fastPutProm = Promise.promisify(sftp.fastPut);`, `fastPutProm` is a function with three arguments. But when I try to run this code, I get a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'fastPut' of undefined` error. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That error means that your `sftp` value is `undefined` so when you try to pass `sftp.fastPut` to the `promisify()` method, it generates an error because you're trying to reference `undefined.fastPut` which is a `TypeError`.

So, the solution is to back up a few steps and figure out why `sftp` doesn't have the desired value in it.

---

Another possibility is that the error is coming from inside the module and it's because the implementation of `sftp.fastPut` is referencing `this` which it expects to be `sftp`.  Your method of promisifying is not preserving the value of `this`.  You can fix that by changing your code to:

```
const fastPutProm = Promise.promisify(sftp.fastPut, {context: sftp});
```

Comment: But that is not the case. If  I put a breakpoint and inspect it, `sftp` is a variable of type `SFTPWrapper`

Comment: @AyushISM - Instead of a breakpoint, do a `console.log(sftp)` right before your promisify line and look at that result there.  Also, please tells us exactly what line of code the error is being reported for.  Maybe it's elsewhere in your code.

Comment: `console.log()` is showing the same info as breakpoint. The error is being reported for the `return fastPutProm(config.jpgDirectory, nasPath, {});` line.

Comment: @AyushISM - But, there's no reference to `fastPut` on that line.  How can that be the line responsible for the error.

Comment: @AyushISM - Can you show us the code for `sftp.fastPut()`?  Does it use the value of `this` inside the implementation?  If so, you have to pass the `sftp` context to the `promisify()` method.  See the `context` option on [Bluebird's `.promisify()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html).  Perhaps try this: `const fastPutProm = Promise.promisify(sftp.fastPut, {context: sftp});`

Comment: That worked.`sftp` is coming from a node module, I didn't write it myself. I'm guessing they're using `this` in the module. If you edit your post with this solution, I'll accept it as the answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AyushISM - Added it to my answer.  They key piece of information was to see where in the stack trace the error was originating.  It was apparently originating inside the other module, not in your code.